# Checking ListViewItemCollection if an element exists

Tags: c#

I have this code today:

```
MyListView.Items[index].Selected = true;
```

And I want to control that the value of index is valid. How do I check within the ListViewItemCollection if that element exists?

Comment: Can you work with `MyListView.Items.Count` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to check if index is within the range of the collection before trying to access it if you do not wish for an IndexOutOfRangeException to be thrown.

This can be done something like this:

```
if (index < MyListView.Items.Count()){
    MyListView.Items[index].selected = true;
} else {
    // handle the index being outside the collection
}
```

Comment: And check for `index >= 0`, if you want to be extra careful.

Comment: Indeed. I assumed that this would be within a for loop, where index = 0; index < items.Count(). That assumption might be wrong, so that makes this valid.